# How to know whether my each java programs is running on its own different JVM instance?

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm

I am running many different java programs simultaneously on single System, 
I need to check whether these programs are running on same or different JVM instance of 
perticular System ?

All suggestions are appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One JVM = one process. A process that's named either `java` or `javaw`.

You can also use [visualvm](http://visualvm.java.net/) to see all running Java processes.

This tool can be found if you install Java JDK. As Steve B. already mentioned, `jps` is also included in JDK.

Comment: Thanks for reply, Can we execute some java code immediately before JVM shutdown/terminate? Or exactly before new JVM going to start?

Comment: @SmartSolution: try using a [shutdown hook](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread)), although this won't guarantee your code will run before JVM shutdown. As for executing code before JVM starting, not really sure about this, unless you're starting a new JVM from a Java program using [exec](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String[])).

Answer (score 2):

`jps` will show you the running java processes on your system.

Comment: Can we execute some java code immediately before JVM shutdown/terminate? Or exactly before new JVM going to start?